# Having trouble figuring out how to pass a file through my method

Tags: java, loops, file, methods, hashmap

In this program I'm working on is to readfile through my method named homophone which reads the file and uses a hashmap to find the words that has the most homophones and returns the count of the number of homophones that was the most. My problem is how do I read the file and pass it through the homophone method in the main method. Here is my code so far:

```
import java.security.KeyStore.Entry;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class program2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
       System.out.println(homophone());
    }

    public static int homophone(String file) throws  FileNotFoundException{
        HashMap<String,Integer> alike = new HashMap<>();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(new File(file));

        while(input.hasNext()) {
            String line = input.nextLine();
            String[] key = line.split("  ");
            if(alike.containsKey(key[1])) {
                alike.put(key[1],alike.get(key[1])+1);
            } else alike.put(key[1],alike.get(key[1]));
        }
        int max = 0;
        for(java.util.Map.Entry<String, Integer> e:alike.entrySet()) {
            if(e.getValue()>max) max = e.getValue();
        }
        return max;
    }
}


Example File Content:
A  AH0
A(1)  EY1
A'S  EY1 Z
A.  EY1
A.'S  EY1 Z
A.S  EY1 Z
A42128  EY1 F AO1 R T UW1 W AH1 N T UW1 EY1 T
AAA  T R IH2 P AH0 L EY1
AABERG  AA1 B ER0 G
AACHEN  AA1 K AH0 N
AACHENER  AA1 K AH0 N ER0
AAKER  AA1 K ER0
AALSETH  AA1 L S EH0 TH
AAMODT  AA1 M AH0 T
AANCOR  AA1 N K AO2 R
AARDEMA  AA0 R D EH1 M AH0
AARDVARK  AA1 R D V AA2 R K
AARON  EH1 R AH0 N
AARON'S  EH1 R AH0 N Z
AARONS  EH1 R AH0 N Z
```

Comment: Probably what you want is homophone(args[0]);

Comment: have you tried passing your file to the homophone method as a file type instead of a string? EX:     public static int homophone(File file) throws  FileNotFoundException{

Comment: @Llama yes unfortuanately it just produces the error : the constructor File(file) is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You need pass a String to your homophone method like that:

```
System.out.println(homophone("/folder/file.txt"));
```

Or

```
System.out.println(homophone(args[0]));
```

Using the second one, you will need to compile and use a system command line like that:

```
java program2 "/folder/file.txt"
```

Comment: Ahh your first option did the trick but more problems show up after that. It ends up giving me no output. It seems the problem is with my homophone method. The code seems to make sense but its somehow wrong still

Comment: I recommend putting a example file in your question, to people test it.